# Human Nameparser with python2.7 not giving desired output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to parse the human names using the Nameparser library of python.
here is what I did and what I got:

```
from nameparser import HumanName
>>> name = HumanName("jafferwilson")
>>> name
<HumanName : [
        title: ''
        first: 'jafferwilson'
        middle: ''
        last: ''
        suffix: ''
        nickname: ''
]>
>>> name = HumanName("jaffer wilson")
>>> name
<HumanName : [
        title: ''
        first: 'jaffer'
        middle: ''
        last: 'wilson'
        suffix: ''
        nickname: ''
]>
```

What I was willing to achieve is when I give input as `jafferwilson` I should get the output as `jaffer wilson` but getting a combined output as `jafferwilson`

Kindly, help me what I can do to achieve what I am thinking to.

Comment: How do you expect the parser to know where to split the words without the whitespace?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thats is the only problem what I am into. Can anyone help with it? Any approach?

Comment: But your name could be "Jaff Erwilson" though, surely it is impossible to know, although you could guess with a sufficiently large database of names

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah .. true. But  thinking to apply an approach that can give me atleast 90% correct result for serach..